# Q: How to call a template class in main, with std::vector?

Tags: c++

I have a template class of a vector, using std::vector:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    std::vector<T> mData; // data stored in vector
    int mSize; // size of vector

public:
    // copy constructor
  Vector(const Vector<T>& otherVector)
    {
        mSize = otherVector.mSize;
        mData = otherVector.mData;
        
    }
Vector(int size)
    {
        assert(size > 0);
        mSize = size;
        mData = std::vector<T>();
        for (int i=0; i<mSize; i++)
        {
            mData.push_back(0.0); //Appends new row with value 0
        }
    }
};
```

How do i call a copy constructor of a template class in my main. For instance if i want a vector of [2,3]?

```
int main(){
Vector<double> v;
v(2,3);
}
```

It's not this:, but what is it?

Comment: You didn't provide a constructor for those arguments, and it's not a copy operation, so I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want a (non-copy) constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list<T>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a page out of `std:vector`'s book, by adding a constructor that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) argument, like this:

```
Vector (std::initializer_list <T> il)
{
    for (auto e : il)
        mData.push_back (e);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Vector <int> v ( { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );
```